# Jmeter is not passing the Microsoft authentication in my script for testing performance on my test website, showing Access denied

Tags: authentication, jmeter

My application has a microsoft authentication on it before logging into it & I have recorded script but when I am running it, it is showing me access denied error everytime.I have set authentication manager but still same error. See image attached.

I have tried `HTTP Authentication Manager` & provided login username & password.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your application uses [OAuth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad) therefore it is neither something you can really record and replay nor handle with the HTTP Authorization Manager.

Depending on your application setup you will either need:

1. To perform [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start) of the query parameters
2. Or to pass the relevant [Authorization Bearer](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/) token via [HTTP Header Manager](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager). The process of obtaining the token can be different depending on your application login chain implementation, check out [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article to get a couple of ideas regarding bypassing 3rd-party provider login challenge in JMeter tests.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you can provide the auth credentials as parameter of the requests.

for example www.abc.com?username=abc&password=abc. Replicate the same with Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

Use [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler) (or you can get away with browser dev tools if you don't mind searching manually) and log in manually via your browser.

Check the request(s) that are submitted to Microsoft for tokens/GUIDs and search for where the browser got those strings from (it'll be in one of the previous requests' responses' bodies or redirect URLs. In Fiddler you can use the find function on responses, browser dev tools you'll have to find it manually).

You can then use a JMeter `Regular Expression Extractor` post-processor (or any of the other post processors you prefer) to extract that string from the earlier request into a variable.
In your login request you can then use the value of that variable (if you used regular expression post-processor with a capture group the first group's value will be `${variable_g1}`

You'll probably have an anti-forgery value that you can extract from the HTML of the login page which needs to be submitted with the username and password and then in the response you'll get a cookie set and potentially JWT token in the response body/URL.